# Infinitely many solutions to an equation with primes: $pqr+22=s$? (open problem)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

The question that I am talking about is:

> A natural number $n$ has property $(*)$, if $n=pqrs$, product of $4$ distinct primes, and, if we order its $16$ divisors, i.e. $$1=d_1<d_2<...<d_{16}=n,$$we have: $d_9-d_8=22$.
> Are there infinitely many numbers $n$, that satisfy $(*)$ ?

In fact, by discussing the cases of $s$, compared with the other primes, the above problem is equivalent to finding solutions to one of the following equations: ($p<q<r<s$)

$1) s=pqr+22$, if $pqr<s$;

$2) s=pqr-22$, if $qr<s<pqr$;

$3) ps=22+qr$, if $qr/p<s<qr$;

$4) qr=22+ps$, if $s<qr/p$.

If any of $1)-4)$ has infinitely many solutions, then the original problem is solved.

My attempt to the first one, treated separately:

First of all, it is easy to notice that $p,q,r \neq 2,11.$
I tried to reduce the degrees of freedom, by setting, for example, $p=3,q=5$, in order to get some sort of arithmetic progressions, but I don't know if Dirichlet's theorems can help.

P.S. The above question is derived from $1995$ Irish Math Olympiad problem. At that time, the task was similar to finding the minimum solution, that is $n=3\cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 19$, which is a solution to $3)$. My apologies for asking such a difficult question.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: The problem is still open, although I have accepted an answer (or comment), for being the most relevant.

Comment: Hard to imagine that this will have a short proof of any sort.  Perhaps it would help if you included the original problem.

Comment: So you have then to show that $15p+22$ is prime for infinitely many primes $p$. This is indeed the case, but as lulu says ...

Comment: In fact , the statement is much weaker , but nevertheless a proof will be out of reach. That $s-22$ is squarefree with three prime factors for infinite many positive integers $s$ seems inevitable, but as so often, questions a child can ask often turn out to be impossible to decide , when it comes to problems about primes.

Comment: @lulu I included the original problem. In fact, there are $4$ equations, not just $1$, but I think that the first one is the easiest to tackle.

Comment: We don't even know if $p+2=s$ has infinitely many solutions in primes.

Comment: How many such quadruples have you found?  It seems difficult, since, in getting to $d_8$ and $d_9$ you need to incorporate all the primes you have.

Comment: Well, I can run a computer to find some solutions for relatively small numbers, but even this would be insufficient.

Comment: I am skeptical that this has any sort of sensible solution.  The original question does not ask you to show that there are infinitely many, nor even that there is one!  All it asks is that you rule out small solutions.

Comment: My computer was able to generate over $4000$ solutions, just for $r$ prime and $15r+22$ to be prime.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  The source is the final question [here](https://imomath.com/othercomp/Ire/IreMO95.pdf).  As you'll see, it is a very different (and much easier) problem...nothing about constructing infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Yes, I am very aware of it, but I am the one who raised the question of how many solutions it has.

Comment: We may use the fact that every prime $p> 5$ is of the form $30k+r$ where $r=1, 7, 11, 13, 19, 23, 29$. Some examples:

$k=11, r=7\rightarrow p=30\times 11+7=337$

$330-15+22=337$

$330-15=315=3^2\times 5\times 7$ 

$k=13, r=7\rightarrow p=390+7=397$

$390-15+22=397$

$390-15=375=3\times 5^3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER, it is just a comment maybe not impertinent and it is put here for obvious reasons of space.

It is clear that $2$ must be discarded. For all pair of odd primes $p,q$ the diophantine equation $px-qy=22$ has infinitely many integer solutions in such a way that there are infinitely many primes for $x$ and $y$ (Dirichlet). The point is that for our purpose we need these primes appear  simultaneously (*which could deserve to be an interesting problem maybe*). We look at some examples.

$$3x-5y=22\iff(x,y)=(5n+4,3n-2)\Rightarrow n=3 \space\text {gives }(r,s)=(19,7)\\5x-7y=22\iff(x,y)=(7n+3,5n-1)\Rightarrow n=4 \space\text {gives }(r,s)=(31,19)\\13x-17y=22\iff(x,y)=(17n+3,13n+1)\Rightarrow n=4 \space\text {gives }(r,s)=(19,7)$$
It must be said that it could be the case that only one of this class of equations is sufficient (to show which would ultimately be a refinement of Dirichlet's Theorem). Another thing is that we have not taken into account the required eighth and ninth position but have limited ourselves to finding four odd primes.

Comment: I agree with this ,,refinement''. I apology for asking such an impossible question, I was hoping that there is a hidden proof, along those strong theorems you mentioned.

Comment: I don't feel any reason for apology, dear friend. Your porblem is difficult but not exent of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Comment:

Based on finding of OP by computer using prime generator $15m+22$ and my comment that all primes are of the form $30k+r$ where $r=1, 7, 11, 13, 17. 19, 23, 29$ we solve following Diophantine equation for every r:

$30k+r=15m+22$$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$

Here for example I solve it for $r=7$:

$p=30k+7=15m+22$

Or:

$2k-m=1$

General form of solutions are:

$(k, m)=(t+2, 2t+3)$

Such that:

$p=30(t+2)+7=15(2t+3)+22=30t+67$

In this way prime generator $p=30t+67$ can give primes satisfying the condition, some examples:

$t=1\rightarrow p=107=22+5\times17$

$t=2\rightarrow p=127=22+5\times 19$

We may try other values for r and solve equation (1) such that the result is $p=22+pqr$ and show experimentally that there can be infinite such primes.

Comment: When trying particular cases for $p$ and $q$, I was thinking along these lines. The solutions generated by computer seem to appear regularly, but this is not a true argument to finish the question.